# How to adjust the table size if it is too wide

Tags: tables, width

everyone, I have a question about fixing the width of the table in my paper. The code is shown below. Since there are too many contents in the same row in the table, it looks too large for my paper. How could I fix the problem? I have already tried the command resizebox, but it doesn't work well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\scriptsize
\caption{}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\hline         
\hline
Low
& \multicolumn{2}{l}{\makecell[l]{19. Leathers,Furs and related products (1.35\%)\\21. Furniture Manufacturing (1.48\%)\\18. Garments, Footwear and Related Products (1.55\%) \\ 43. Recycling  and Disposal of Waste (1.56\%)\\ 42. Manufacturing, n.e.c. (1.57\%) \\20. Timber Processing and Related Products (1.72\%) \\24.  Cultural,Edu. and Sport Goods (2.61\%) \\ 17. Textiles (2.74\%) \\13. Food Processing (3.77\%) \\ 34. Metal Products (3.86\%) }} 
& \multicolumn{2}{l}{%
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\makecell[l]{19. Leathers,Furs and related products (4.17\%) \\18. Garments, Footwear and Related Products (5.39\%)\\ 42. Manufacturing, n.e.c. (5.67\%) \\24.  Cultural,Edu. and Sport Goods (5.87\%) \\ 17. Textiles (6\%)  \\21. Furniture Manufacturing (7.67\%)\\20. Timber Processing and Related Products (7.76\%)  \\29. Rubber Products (9.88\%) \\31. Nonmetal Mineral Products (10.01\%)\\30. Plastic Products (10.02\%)}
  \end{tabular}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Read through [page breaking - My table doesn't fit; what are my options? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options?noredirect=1&lq=1) and try using solutions there first.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you specify the `tabular` environment to have five columns when there really are only three columns. I would get rid of the `\multicolumn` and `\makecell` wrappers and use a `tabularx` environment to allow automatic line breaking (with hanging indentation) in both data columns; do also replace almost all instances of `\\` in the data columns with `\newline`.

Oh, and I would switch from `\scriptsize` to `\small` -- your readers will appreciate this gesture of kindness and good will.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{\small 19.\space} % measure width of hanging indentation
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=\mylen}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\small % '\scriptsize' is much too small for comfortable reading
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{\dots} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}cLL@{}}
\toprule
Low  & 
19. Leathers, furs and related products (1.35\%)\newline
21. Furniture manufacturing (1.48\%)\newline
18. Garments, footwear and related products (1.55\%) \newline 
43. Recycling and disposal of waste (1.56\%)\newline 
42. Manufacturing, n.e.c. (1.57\%) \newline
20. Timber processing and related products (1.72\%) \newline
24. Cultural, edu.\ and sport goods (2.61\%) \newline 
17. Textiles (2.74\%) \newline
13. Food processing (3.77\%) \newline 
34. Metal products (3.86\%) 
& 
19. Leathers, furs and related products (4.17\%) \newline
18. Garments, footwear and related products (5.39\%)\newline 
42. Manufacturing, n.e.c. (5.67\%) \newline
24. Cultural, edu.\ and sport goods (5.87\%) \newline 
17. Textiles (6\%) \newline
21. Furniture manufacturing (7.67\%)\newline
20. Timber processing and related products (7.76\%) \newline
29. Rubber products (9.88\%) \newline
31. Nonmetal mineral products (10.01\%)\newline
30. Plastic products (10.02\%) 
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```